# Placing two columns of Checkboxbar in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I wish to place two CheckboxBar columns in a Manipulate; the first column would be the branch CheckboxBar and the other column, the phase checkboxBar in the code below.  However Column and Grid do not display the check boxes when I attempt to add it to the code and I was wondering if it's even possible to arrange CheckboxBars like this and if so, if someone could help me?  I've searched the side and could not find a thread dealing specifically with checkbox bars arranged so however.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], branchList, phaseList}],
 {{branchList, {}, ""}, Table[m -> ToString[m] <> " Branch", {m, 6}], 
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar, Appearance -> ("Vertical")},
 {{phaseList, {}, ""}, Table[m -> ToString[m] <> " Phase", {m, 6}], 
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar, Appearance -> ("Vertical")},
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
 Row[{Control@{{branchList, {}, ""}, 
     Table[m -> ToString[m] <> " Branch", {m, 6}], 
     ControlType -> CheckboxBar, Appearance -> ("Vertical")}, 
   Control@{{phaseList, {}, ""}, 
     Table[m -> ToString[m] <> " Phase", {m, 6}], 
     ControlType -> CheckboxBar, Appearance -> ("Vertical")}}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Manipulate[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
 Grid[{{Control@{{branchList, {}, ""}, 
      Table[m -> ToString[m] <> " Branch", {m, 6}], 
      ControlType -> CheckboxBar, Appearance -> ("Vertical")}, 
    Control@{{phaseList, {}, ""}, 
      Table[m -> ToString[m] <> " Phase", {m, 6}], 
      ControlType -> CheckboxBar, Appearance -> ("Vertical")}}}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks!  I can make that work.

Comment: @Kglr can you tell how to change the vertical spacing between these checkboxes?

Comment: @Rupesh, don't know otomh how to control vertical spacings in `CheckboxBar`. I suggest you post it as a new question.

Comment: @kglr thank you for looking into it.